# How to pass parameters to laravel factory in database seeder?

Tags: php, laravel, factory, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

Is it possible to pass data from seeder to factory?

This is my `PictureFactory`:

```
class PictureFactory extends Factory{

    protected $model = Picture::class;

    public function definition($galleryId = null, $news = false){
       if (!is_null($galleryId)){
            $galley = Gallery::find($galleryId);
            $path = 'public/galleries/' . $galley->name;
            $newsId = null;
         }
        if ($news){
            $path = 'public/newsPicture';
            $newsId = News::all()->random(1);
        }

        $pictureName = Faker::word().'.jpg';
        return [
            'userId' => 1,
            'src' =>$this->faker->image($path,400,300, 2, false) ,
            'originalName' => $pictureName,
            'newsId' => $newsId
       ];
    }
}
```

and I use it like this in database seeder:

```
News::factory(3)
    ->has(Comment::factory()->count(2), 'comments')
    ->create()
    ->each(function($news) { 
        $news->pictures()->save(Picture::factory(null, true)->count(3)); 
    });
```

but `$galleryId` and `$news` do not pass to `PictureFactory`. Where did I go wrong? And what should I do? please help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that [factory states](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-states) were made for. Assuming you are using a current (8.x) version of Laravel, define your factory like this:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories\App;

use App\Models\{Gallery, News, Picture};
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class PictureFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = Picture::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'userId' => 1,
            'originalName' => $this->faker->word() . '.jpg',
       ];
    }

    public function withGallery($id)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::findOrFail($id);
        $path = 'public/galleries/' . $gallery->name;

        return $this->state([
            'src' => $this->faker->image($path, 400, 300, 2, false),
            'newsId' => null,
        ]);
    }

    public function withNews()
    {
         $news = News::inRandomOrder()->first();
         $path = 'public/newsPicture';

         return $this->state([
            'src' => $this->faker->image($path, 400, 300, 2, false),
            'newsId' => $news->id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And now you can create your desired models like this:

```php
Picture::factory()->count(3)->withNews();
// or
Picture::factory()->count(3)->withGallery($gallery_id);
```

I'm not certain, but I believe you should be able to do this to get your desired outcome:

```php
Picture::factory()
    ->count(3)
    ->withNews()
    ->for(News::factory()->hasComments(2))
    ->create();
```